# Is there any way to do a recursive partial with a new member in Typescript

Tags: typescript, recursion, types, partial

## Summary

I have these `type`'s. However, I cannot figure out how to make a recursive partial with new member.

## Example

#### `PartialWithNewMember`:

```
type PartialWithNewMember<T> = {
  [P in keyof T]?: T[P];
} & { newMember: boolean }
```

#### `RecursivePartial`:

```
type RecursivePartial<T> = {
  [P in keyof T]?: RecursivePartial<T[P]>;
};
```

### Attempted Solution

This is the closest I could get which works but seems like a hack ‍♂️

```
type RecursivePartialWithNewMembers<T> =
  | ({
      [P in keyof T]?: RecursivePartialWithNewMembers<T[P]>;
    } & { [key: string]: any })
  | T;
```

My use case is allowing a consumer of a redux-like store I am using to pass in an `initialState` with additional and omitted properties. However, I would like all properties that do match keys to be of the correct types.

## Edit: Added example

Here's an example of what I'm trying to do.

I want to create a `Store` type. That can have properties *added* and *omitted* whilst keeping the existing properties typed correctly.

### Example

#### `createStore` function exported from a library NPM package

```
interface Market {
  locale: string;
}

interface Tenant {
  id: string;
}

interface Customer {
  id: string;
  hasProduct?: boolean;
}

interface Product {
  id: string;
  title: string;
  price: number;
}

interface State {
  market: Market;
  tenant: Tenant;
  customer: Customer;
  product: Product;
}

// Export a function that can be called from other packages and will return a redux-like store with state (of type State with props added or omitted)
export const createStore = (initialState: RecursivePartialWithNewMembers<State>, actions: RecursivePartialWithNewMembers<Actions>) => { ... };
```

#### `createStore` function imported from first tenant web app

```
import createStore from '@somePackage';

// `customer` property is omitted; `product.relatedProducts` property is added;
const initialState = {
  market: {
    id: 'US'
  },
  tenant: {
    id: 'first',
  },
  product: {
    id: '',
    title: '',
    price: 0,
    relatedProducts: []
  }
};

const store = createStore(initialState, actions);
```

#### `createStore` function imported from second tenant web app

```
import createStore from '@somePackage';

// `product.price` property is omitted; `customer.devices` property is added;
const initialState = {
  market: {
    id: '',
    locale:
  },
  tenant: {
    id: ''
  },
  customer: {
    id: '',
    hasProduct: false,
    devices: []
  },
  product: {
    id: '',
    title: ''
  }
};

const store = createStore(initialState, actions);
```

Comment: What are the new members?  I don't understand the type you're trying to build. Can you give a concrete example (that is, make a concrete interface `Foo` and show what you want `RecursivePartialWithNewMembers<Foo>` to be)?

Comment: I added an example . The new members are dynamic. Each usage of the `createStore` should be able to pass in a different extension of the `State` with properties *added* or *omitted*.

Comment: Your example mentions `Actions`, which isn't defined anywhere.   Could you try to ensure that any example code constitutes a [mcve] suitable for dropping into a standalone IDE like [The Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/)?  I notice that you didn't include what you expect `RecursivePartialWithNewMembers<State>` to be.  It's harder to imagine giving you an implementation for `RecursivePartialWithNewMembers` if you don't know what the output type should look like.

Comment: Does [this](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/C4TwDgpgBASgCgdQHIFkA8AVAfFAvFDKCAD2AgDsATAZygHsAjAKwgGNgoB+KAbygG0A0lACW5KAGsIIOgDMCAXU4AuWIlSYhCnAF8oAMl4CJq6sABOYgOYLVAV3ITydAO7i9qjAG4AUFB9iZOayAIas0Cgh5lIcPH5QADZ0rCEJEKYW1r46PgHkQaHhBBQh+bzxIpQZluRW2bmBEMFh0ADCdmZ0ALZN5VCiVVBmNXXxABYh1HDmdJR27CpQDHR0aaX1eQUtUNOz87EVg8NZ8cAiwGnVJ-1gluGq5HZdDE0bjc1FAMrAIWR9UF0ojFVJFohBgL5+mRyKVgJ4SvlIVBWB1gN0mqp2p0euYkbc9uxVLs5uwNqBIFAAPJ2YBgGnfX7QfDwZDoBlkLC+HxAA) work for you?  If so I'll write up an answer.